# Terminal Services commands available in a .NET namespace?

Tags: .net-3.5, terminal-services

Are there .NET equivalent commands to terminal services commands 'QWINSTA', 'RWINSTA', AND 'TSDISCON'?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently there is no .NET / managed API equivalent.  You can probably use the functions in **wtsapi32.dll** though. Check out [pinvoke.net](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/wtsapi32/TerminalServices.html) for some examples of how to invoke these from managed code... starting with the following:

[WTSEnumerateSessions](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/wtsapi32.WTSEnumerateSessions)

[WTSQuerySessionInformation](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/wtsapi32.WTSQuerySessionInformation)

[WTSLogoffSession](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/wtsapi32/WTSLogoffSession.html)

Or, if you don't want to roll your own Win32 wrapper, check out the "[cassia](http://code.google.com/p/cassia/)" project.  I have not used it and therefore cannot vouch for the quality of this solution, however it seems to be a .NET library used for accessing the native Windows Terminal Services API.

The following is an example of how you would use the cassia library in C# (taken from the project site):

```
ITerminalServicesManager manager = new TerminalServicesManager();
using (ITerminalServer server = manager.GetRemoteServer("your-server-name"))
{
    server.Open();
    foreach (ITerminalServicesSession session in server.GetSessions())
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Session ID: " + session.SessionId);
        Console.WriteLine("User: " + session.UserAccount);
        Console.WriteLine("State: " + session.ConnectionState);
        Console.WriteLine("Logon Time: " + session.LoginTime);
    }
}
```